# SSRS Remote Errors Enabled but NOT Working

Tags: sql, sharepoint-2010, reporting-services

SSRS Remote Errors Enabled but NOT Working,

I have enabled report errors on a report server in sp integrated mode and still get the following error:

“For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors”

I have checked the report server which is reporting “remote errors = true” and the server has been restarted

Other information: I am using Report Builder 3 to develop my reports then I am publishing to SharePoint but the only appears when rendering in SP (2010 & SQL Server R2 upgrade)

Answer (score 2):

I bet your SSRS is running on a server that is not your web front end, right?  SSRS will not pass most errors forward for the WFE to display.  Best way to debug report errors is to setup a host entry on your SSRS server and hit the reports directly from your SSRS server.  The other option if you don't have local access to the server is to set the host entry to the SSRS server on your local machine and hit it directly that way.

Hope this can help anyone who comes across this as this is an older question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, even after I enabled remote errors in Central Admin.  Check the SharePoint site setting for the area where you store your reports.

Site Settings > Report Services > Reporting Services Site Settings and make sure "Enable remote errors in local mode" is ticked.

After ticking this, I saw the detailed error messages when I tried to open the reports.

Hope it helps!